# ¿Cómo hacer esta tarjeta usando CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a realizar esta tarjeta usando `CSS`?

[image: forma]

He utilizado el pseudo elemente `::before` para realizar la forma diagonal pero al hacerlo así los dos bordes redondeados quedan cuadrados y necesito que queden redondos.

Gracias de antemano.

```css
.card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 3rem;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: rgba(3, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.15rem 0.5rem, rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.075rem 0.175rem;
    transition: all 400ms;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-folder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    background: #353535;
}

.card-folder::before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid #fff;
    border-right: 215px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-folder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías añadir no que haz intentado, osea tu código css

Comment: No es nada del otro mundo, solo es un div con un width, un height y un border-radius; ese es el motivo por el cuál no agregué un code snippet. Lo importante realmente es lograr la forma diagonal superior.

Comment: Por que no usas una imagen?

Comment: Porque planeo realizar shape-animations que no serían posibles si utilizo imágenes

Comment: Hola @JuanGarcía, ¿qué fuente tipográfica utilizas en la figura (imagen) que tienes en tu publicación?

Comment: Hola @DavidE.LunaM. Open Sans - semi bold 400,600


https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans:400,600

Comment: @JuanGarcía Ok, estoy creando la figura. La tengo casi lista, pero antes de que te la responda agrega algo de código **HTML** y **CSS** de cómo crees que debería escribirse. Te avisaré en cuanto la tenga. Estoy trabajando en ella.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Gracias. Agregué un code snippet de lo que tengo; como se puede ver los bordes superiores no son redondos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espero que esto te ayude:

```css
*, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.carpet {
  background-color: #9a85fc;
  height: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px 0 7px 7px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1
}

.carpet::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -28px;
  left: 0;
  height: 27px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
  border-color: transparent #9a85fc     transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 28px 195px 0 0;
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f9b471;
  z-index: -2;
  width: 180px;
  left: 10px;
}

.shadow::before {
  border-color: transparent #f9b471     transparent transparent;
  width: 180px;
  border-width: 27px 175px 0 0;
  top: -27px;
}

.shadow-2 {
  top: -25px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #de6e7a;
  z-index: -3;
}

.shadow-2::before {
  border-color: transparent #de6e7a     transparent transparent;
  width: 160px;
  border-width: 27px 155px 0 0;
  top: -27px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carpet"></div>
  <div class="carpet shadow"></div>
  <div class="carpet shadow shadow-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Una explicación a a ayudar a hacer más entendible y fácil de recibir tu aporte